# Drupal 6 - Content profile fields within page-user.tpl.php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

Going a bit mad here... :)

I'm just trying to add CCK fields from a Content Profile content type into page-user.tpl.php (I'm creating a highly-themed user profile page).

There seem to be two methods, both of which have a unique disadvantage that I can't seem to overcome:

**'$content profile' method.**

```
$var = $content_profile->get_variables('profile');

print $var['field_last_name'][0]['safe'];
```

This is great, except I can't seem to pass the currently viewed user into $content_profile, and it therefore always shows the logged in user.

**'$content profile load' method.**

```
$account_id = arg(1);
$account = user_load($account_id);
$user_id = $account->uid;

$var = content_profile_load('profile', $user_id);

print $var->field_first_name[0]['value'];
```

Fine, but now I can't access the full rendered fields, only the plain values (i.e. if the field has paragraphs they won't show up).

How can I have both things at once? In other words how can I show fields relating to the currently viewed user that are also rendered (the 'safe' format in 1)?

I've Googled and Googled and I just end up going round in circles. :(

Cheers,
James

Comment: Where are you trying to use these? please explain a bit about what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your **content profile load method** seems to be the closest to what you want.

In your example:

```
$account_id = arg(1);
$account = user_load($account_id);
$user_id = $account->uid;

$var = content_profile_load('profile', $user_id);

print $var->field_first_name[0]['value'];
```

The $var is just a node object.  You can get the "full rendered fields" in a number of ways (assuming you mean your field with a filter applied).

The most important thing to check is that you're field is actually configured properly.

Go to:
**admin/content/node-type/[node-type]/fields/field_[field-name]** to configure your field and make sure that under **text processing** that you've got "Filtered text" selected.

If that doesn't fix it,try applying this:

```
content_view_field(content_fields("field_last_name"), $var, FALSE, FALSE)
```

(more info on this here: http://www.trevorsimonton.com/blog/cck-field-render-node-formatter-format-output-print-echo )

in place of this:

```
print $var->field_first_name[0]['value'];
```

if none of that helps... try out some of the things i've got on my blog about this very problem:
http://www.trevorsimonton.com/blog/print-filtered-text-body-input-format-text-processing-node-template-field-php-drupal

Comment: Cheers for the in depth reply, still need to do some testing but some good ideas here!

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating a user profile page there is a built in mechanism for it.  just create a user template file, user_profile.tpl.php.

When you use the built in mechanism you automatically get access to the $account object of the user you are browsing, including all user profile cck fields.  You have the fields you are looking for without having to programmatically load the user.

I have a field called profile_bio and am able to spit out any mark up that is in without ever having to ask for the $account.

```
<?php if ($account->content[Profile][profile_bio]['#value']) print "<h3>Bio</h3>".$account->content[Profile][profile_bio]['#value']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried themeing content profiles by displaying profile node fields through the userpage before and it always seems a little "hacky" to me. What I've grown quite fond of is simply going to the content profile settings page for that node type and setting the display to "Display the full content". This is fine and dandy except for the stupid markup like the node type name that content profile injects.

a solution for that is to add a preprocess function for the content profile template. one that will unset the $title and remove the node-type name that appears on the profile normally.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_content_profile_display_view(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['type'] == 'nodetypename') {
    unset($variables['title']);
  }
}
```

A function similar to this should do the trick. Now to theme user profiles you can simply theme your profile nodes as normal.